# Reputation-based filter for search results

Tags: script, api-v2.2, reputation, search

This userscript filters search results on Stack Exchange sites by reputation of the asker. To use it, add a search parameter such as `is:25` where 25 is the minimum reputation required. Since the search engine interprets `is:number` as allowing both questions and answers, be sure to have something else that restricts the results to questions: for example, `is:q` does this in the query

```
is:q intags:mine is:25
```

(means: questions with my favorite tags, asked by users with 25+ reputation). Other parameters such as `closed:0` or `answers:0` implicitly restrict the results to answers, eliminating the need for `is:q`.

The reason this script overloads `is:` parameter instead of introducing something like `rep:` is that an unrecognized parameter would be treated as text to search for.

[Sample query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=intags%3amine%20answers%3a0%20is%3a25): newest Stack Overflow questions with no answers, within your favorite tags, with asker's reputation 25+.

The script uses Stack Exchange API: one API call per search page load. Since it simply hides some of the search results, one might end up with an empty page. It's best to have page size = 50 in search and set a moderate reputation requirement.

- [Source on GitHub](https://github.com/normalhuman/Userscripts/blob/master/repfilter.user.js)
- [Direct link for installation](https://github.com/normalhuman/Userscripts/raw/master/repfilter.user.js)
- [WTFPL license](http://www.wtfpl.net/)

Comment: Chrome: "Apps, extensions, and user scripts cannot be added from this website."

Comment: I use TamperMonkey to manage userscripts. The link works if one has TamperMonkey installed.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your query correctly but `is:q intags:mine is:4000` does not return questions whose OP has 4000 rep. `:-(`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus The script simply hides the questions from low-reputation users from the page. If all questions on the page get hidden, you get an empty page (paginating to page 2, 3, ... might bring some). This isn't really meant for such high threshold; few questions are asked by 4000+ rep users.

Comment: The link is 404 so the userscript is gone.